# Hyperref with pagebackref requires manual escaping of percentage signs in URLs

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls, back-referencing

URLs in bibliography items with a `%20` (to represent a space) work fine with the package `hyperref` as long as the option `pagebackref` is not used. If it is used, Latex fails with:

```
xxx.bbl:xx: Paragraph ended before \BR@@bibitem was complete,
```

ie, the percentage sign is not automatically escaped and thus the URL field is not properly terminated. Escaping it in the .bib file with a backslash solves the issue but requires manual work every time I generate a new .bib file.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{refID,
  title="title",
  url = {http://www.somesite.com/8%20report}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{refID}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `backref` active, the entire bibliography record in the `.bbl` file is read as an argument, so the category code tricks made by `\url` don't work.

However, the `IEEEtran` bib style provides the hook `\BIBdecl` that's executed at the start of the bibliography; use it to make `%` into a printable character. The produced `.bbl` file shouldn't have comments after `\BIBdecl`, at least as far as I can see.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{refID,
  title="title",
  url = {http://www.somesite.com/8%20report}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\BIBdecl}{\catcode`\%=12 }

\begin{document}
\cite{refID}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, should this work with every bibliography style that has the following lines: 
  "\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}"
  write$ newline$
  "\BIBdecl"
  write$ newline$